# Number of triplets in array

Tags: combinatorics

We have array $a_0,a_1,...,a_n.$
What is number of triplets $(a[i],a[j],a[k])$ where $0\le i,j,k \le n$ and $a[i]\&a[j]\&a[k]=0$?

& is bitwise and

Comment: This can only be answered with an algorithm, since the answer depends on the array. That's not really appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to use the principle of inclusion exclusion. Count the number of triples, $(n+1)^3$. From those, for each bit, subtract the triples which are all one in that bit. Letting $b_i$ be the number of triplets whose $i^{th}$ bit is one, we this leaves
$$
(n+1)^3-b_1^3-b_2^2-\dots-b_k^3,
$$
where $k$ is the largest values for which some $a_i$ has a nonzero $k^{th}$ bit. But we are not done yet... triplets for which $a[i]\,\&\,a[j]\,\&\,a[k]$ is one in two places have been subtracted twice. We need to add these back in. And then subtract the triplets which whose bitwise and is one in three places, and so on. The final result is 
$$
\sum_{S} (-1)^{|S|} b_S^3,
$$
where $S$ ranges over subsets of bits, and $b_S$ is the number of $a_i$ which are one for all bits in $S$.